# Showing database table names and their column numbers

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

So I want to see how many columns each of my table in a database library has.

I use

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'library';
```

to see the names and I can see the row count, however, I am not sure how to make it show the columns as well. In fact I only need names and column number, but I'm not sure how to ask to see names either. I tried

```
show tables from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'library';
```

but I guess that's absolutely wrong, as an error comes up as well

Comment: " I am not sure how to make it show the columns as well." Check information_schema.COLUMNS table

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have done that but what it does, it lists the column names, types as well, which I don't need. all I need is a name and column count there. I can probably do it separately for each table but I was wondering if I can just make it work on all tables in a given database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
SELECT table_name, COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'Library' Group by table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `information_schema.columns`:

```
select t.*, c.*
from information_schema.tables t join
     information_schema.columns c
     on t.table_schema = c.table_schema and t.table_name = c.table_name
where t.table_schema = 'library';
```